# Issues with buttons, clock control from previous screen overlay on current screen before refresh

Tags: ios, codenameone

In iPhone App there is an issue of buttons from previous screen appear on the current screen when the screen got loaded. they will disappear when the refresh is manually triggered. I have used white and blue colors for the App. is there any way I can avoid happening this. This is only occurs on IOS App and not on Android App

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

[image: Image3]

Comment: Hi @Chris L please add some more information about your code, or add some screenshots for more reference.

Comment: You probably won't clean up your old resources well enough.

Comment: are you adding the components on the view controllers or on the window?

Comment: Do you mean that buttons loaded in a Form are also loaded in another Form without any apparent reason?

Comment: Yes Thats correct. Buttons from another form loads without reason and will disappear after refreshing the page or on touch of the finger.

Comment: Did you change the UIID of the form or set the styles? This can happen if you manipulate the transparency of the form itself.

Comment: Attached images for reference.

Comment: Yes Shai. I did set the UIID for controls but I haven't set any UIID for form itself. I have changed the transparency for every control as per the need of my requirement. In this situation is there a workaround?. This seems like happening mostly on iOS devices. Please advise.

Comment: Setting the UIID for form will help in anyways. Please advise. on setting the UIID for form.

Comment: Please advise if anyone encounter the same issue. Thanks.